# How many subnets required in a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I wish to implement my website in AWS virtual private cloud (VPC) with the following requirement:

1. The web tier will use an Auto Scaling group across multiple Availability Zones (AZs).
2. The database will use Multi-AZ RDS MySQL and should not be publicly accessible.

What is the minimal number of subnets required?

I assume one subnet = one AZ. Having said that, I will be needing 2 subnets for the RDS instance and one for my web tier which might have to sit in the public subnets? so total 3 minimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- Do everything in **Public Subnets**, using Security Groups to protect your database, or
- Use **Public & Private Subnets**

If both options, you would need:

- An Amazon VPC
- An Internet Gateway (which connects the VPC to the Internet)
- An Elastic Load Balancer
- An Auto Scaling group of Amazon EC2 instances running your web tier
- An Amazon RDS Multi-AZ database -- you have indicated a preference for MySQL

Also, you would **create three security groups**:

- A **Load Balancer security group**, permitting inbound traffic from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`) for HTTP (port 80) and presumably HTTPS (port 443)
- A **Web Tier security group**, permitting inbound traffic from the Load Balancer security group on the same ports
- A **Database security group**, permitting inbound traffic from the Web Tier security group on port 3306 (MySQL)

**Option 1: Do everything in public subnets**

In this option, you can put all services inside a Public Subnet (which is defined as a subnet connected to the Internet via an Internet Gateway). 
You wish to implement a multi-AZ solution, so you will need one subnet per AZ. If you choose to use two AZs, this means you will need two subnets. (You could choose to use more than two AZs/subnets, if they are available in your region.)

Deploy your **Load Balancer** in both subnets. Create your **Auto Scaling group** to use both subnets. Create an **Amazon RDS DB Subnet Group** across both subnets for use by the multi-AZ database and launch the database into that DB Subnet Group.

The security groups will ensure that only the Load Balancer is exposed to the Internet. Nothing else will be publicly accessible.

**Option 2: Use Public & Private Subnets**

Some people prefer using Private Subnets to ensure resources are not exposed to the Internet. This is mostly to remain compatible with traditional on-premises architecture that does not have the concept of a Security Group.

This option would involve:

- A **Public Subnet** in each AZ: Put your Load Balancer in these subnets
- A **Private Subnet** in each AZ: Put your Web Tier Auto Scaling group and your database in these subnets (defined via the DB Subnet Group)
- Use the same **Security Groups** as option 1

Comment: wow !! That's an awesome explanation. Crystal clear, Thank's John.

Comment: Hi @John, do you know how I can decide if I should associate my VPC with ipv6? would clients with ipv6 be able to connect to my services that are in VPC associated with ipv4 only?

Comment: Your own software will also need to support IPv6. For example, the operating system would need it activated on the EC2 instance and you should test your software using IPv6. Only activate IPv6 if you have done that. Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for 3 subnet.

If you put 2 subnet in different AZ and 1 is public and 1 is private that is also able to communicate with each other because of in 1 VPC multi-pal instance can calumniate with each other and different.

But if you put 3 subnet in different AZ as you said that is better for security and accessibility from web-server.